# Invalid characters coming from windows-1252 encoded site

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have ran across a problem where I'm getting invalid data from input form
foreign letters like ä,ü,õ,ö are coming through like this (%C3%84, %C3%BC etc)

for example my controller receives a word that contains one of those like this S%C3%BCav.

I have tried converting word into bytes and rebuilding them with other encodings but with no luck

Is there a way in c# that will do this for you or do i have to hardcode in the replacements.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

And as always i ask the question and then realize the obvious

answer was to use HttpUtility.UrlDecode if anyone ever stumbles upon this problem